# How to prevent form submission in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written code like this to prevent form submit. But it is not working. What is the possible reason

```
$('#signUpForm').submit(function (event) {
        debugger;
        console.log('test');
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#signUpForm').unbind().submit();
        //IsValid();
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: [`event.preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) is correct. Have you got a fiddle, or something showing exactly what is not working?

Comment: could you show your DOM code, you could be selecting the wrong Form element

Comment: use *either* `event.preventDefault()` *or* `return false`, there's no need to do both.

Comment: This is jQuery not JavaScript

Comment: @Alexander Lallier I'm sure you'd agree that technically it's both really... jQuery is a JavaScript library and can't exist independently

Comment: jQuery wraps JavaScript and you are technically correct that jQuery can't exist with JavaScript but you cannot say that jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: `you cannot say that jQuery is JavaScript` - getting way off-topic now, but you can, and I do. Every time you use jQuery, you're using javascript, not just in a narrow "technical" sense but in reality. The same with any JS library or framework.

Comment: If you're using JavaScript under the hood you technically are using JS but it's not what you are writing. If you are writing a React app for example and tag JavaScript on here that is incorrect because you cannot technically receive vanilla JS support for that work.

Comment: @Alexander Lallier I disagree. JavaScript is the programming language. jQuery, react, angular etc. are all libraries written in JavaScript. If you use one of them, then you are using JavaScript. Even if you use something like jQuery for everything, sometimes you will still write a line of pure native JS. Even if you don't write pure JS much, all your other lines of code are still JavaScript...they are just lines which happen to invoke functions provided by jQuery. The syntax, keywords etc are all still valid JavaScript. Don't confuse the language with the library.

Comment: @Alexander Lallier ...and that's why I would advise people on this site to add tags both for the programming language they are writing in, _as well as_ any libraries written in that language which they may be using in their application to help them. JS programmers can help with any JS question, potentially. For example, I have never used angular for any reason, but I see questions tagged JS/Angular and I look, and sometimes I can see the answer, either because the solution is actually just a line of regular JS, or because I know enough JS to work out what the angular function is doing

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have only 1 form in your html page

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(e);
      console.log("form submission canceled");
  });
});
```

Comment: this assumes there are no other forms on the page where this behaviour is not needed...we have no idea whether that's the case or not. If you're going to suggest a change like this, you should at least explain any possible unintended consequences, rather than just dumping the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#signUpForm").on("submit",function(e){
      e.preventDefault(e);
      console.log("form submission canceled");
  });
});
```

Comment: this assumes there are no other forms on the page where this behaviour is not needed...we have no idea whether that's the case or not. If you're going to suggest a change like this, you should at least explain any possible unintended consequences, rather than just dumping the code. Also, there's already another answer suggesting the exact same thing...

Answer (score -1):

According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) your syntax seems to be wrong.

Also, `.unbind()` is deprecated. Prefer `.off()`

try

```
 $('#signUpForm').unbind('submit')
```

Comment: You didn't explain what syntax exactly was wrong, and why. And then you state that unbind() is deprecated yet continue to provide a code example using it... Also we don't even know whether this is the problem OP is actually complaining about, since they haven't provided any proper details.

Comment: @ADyson I clearly explain why his syntax is wrong with the code provided

Comment: No you don't, you just state that it's wrong, without even explaining which bit is wrong, or why, or why your change is correct. You given an alternative, but you haven't _explained_ anything

Comment: I also don't understand why you give an example using a method you already mentioned is deprecated